# Word choice: scooted for? Eyes are weary/drooping with sleep?

Tags: word-choice

1. Is it right to say 'Kayla got out of bed and scooted for the toilet?
   I checked the Longman and Oxford dictionaries which explain that 'scooted' may be used with 'off' or 'over', but I'm not sure if it can used with 'for'.
2. Can I also say 'my eyes are weary/drooping with sleep'?
   I think I can say that my eyes are 'heavy' with sleep but are 'weary' and 'drooping' acceptable?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, you can use _scooted_ with _for_ – [these authors have](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22scooted+for+the%22&safe=off&rls=en&prmd=ivns&source=lnms&tbm=bks) :^)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1: "Scooted" has a general usage of "hurried" -- see http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/scoot?s=t -- so if you are making a dash for the toilet, you can scoot to it, sure.

2: "My eyes are weary with sleep" doesn't quite work; being "weary" means being tired, and being "tired with sleep" only works if you're delving into metaphor. (E.g., if you have a condition that makes you sleep too much, and you are always groggy and wanting to go back to sleep.) "My eyes are drooping with sleep" miiiight work? But first, it's generally your eye*lids* that droop[footnote1], and second, it or "heavy with sleep" are going to indicate that you were just woken up and you're still tired. If you mean that your eyelids are drooping *because* you are tired, you want to use "My eyelids are heavy/drooping with fatigue."

If you have eye-strain, though, you can say that your eyes are weary, or weary from [staring at the computer/reading all night/squinting all day].

[Footnote1: Unless your eyes are on stalks, in which case, please bring over your flying saucer so I can take advantage of your advanced technology to fix a few things. Thanks. ;) ]

Comment: I agree with your answer, but I'd like to add that we could say something like, _my eyes were drooping sleepily_. (Like you, I'd interpret _eyes_ to mean "eyelids" in that context.)

Comment: That's true! It's a construction I'd avoid in more formal writing, though, as some readers (or teachers) will be more picky than others, and could be bothered by it.